# Search keyword and return value/blank if both condition match

Tags: excel-formula

Is there any formula can use for below query with refer the sample picture. I scratching my head for the suitable formula of this combination but i not good in here.

(i)How many days use for airplane mode(column Q)/ ship mode (column R)if the destination match.
(ii)If the destination not using airplane or ship mode, return blank.

[image]

Comment: Use SUMIFS() and format the cell so the `0` is shown as blank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the newest versions of Excel you can use `FILTER` and wrap it in an `IFERROR`. Something like:

```
=IFERROR(
FILTER($C$2:$C$13, ($A$2:$A$13=$E2)*($B$2:$B$13=F$1)),
"")
```

Note that if the column of your dataframe is not a name of the form of travel, you will need to replace the `...=F$1` part with the name of the form of travel (like `...="Ship"`

[image]

Comment: Just an FYI, FILTER has a built in error handler. `=FILTER($C$2:$C$13, ($A$2:$A$13=$E2)*($B$2:$B$13=F$1),"")` will do the same without the need for `IFERROR`  One may also want to note that this only works if the combination of Destination and Transportation is unique, that there are no duplication.  Otherwise a #Spill error will occur and your IFERROR would return an errant blank when it should not.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
=IFERROR(1/(1/SUMIFS($N:$N,$L:$L,$P2,$M:$M,MID(Q$1,11,LEN(Q$1)-11))),"")
```

By doing the reciprocal of the reciprocal it will error when the sumifs returns `0` and the IFERROR will return a blank.

If you change the titles in Q1 and R1 to the actual value you are trying to find the
`MID(Q$1,11,LEN(Q$1)-11))` can be changed to just `Q$1`